# what's the mean of "This is in 1/20th of a point."?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, units-of-measurement

this is in the apache POI export Excel document ,I Don't know this sentence mean "This is in 1/20th of a point.";
who can help me! 
I know in this sentence "1/20th" th is length unit,but I Don't know convert this unit;

Comment: This is the type of question you could have easily answered using Google.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] before posting on SO.

Comment: So how is this related to `Java` and `JavaScript`?

Comment: POI has a Java library and could be considered Java-EE, I guess... Editing tags...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote another [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/207):

> In applications, 1pt is equal to exactly 1/72th of an inch; in traditional print technically 72pt is 0.996264 inches, although I think you'll be forgiven for rounding it up!
>
> How many pixels = 1pt depends on the resolution of your image. If your image is 72ppi (pixels per inch), then one point will equal exactly one pixel.

Comment: thank you answered this question !but i don't know this sentence "th" and px how to convert?

Comment: 1/20th means "one twentieth", i.e, 5%.   So 1/20th point is 1/1440th inch. At 72 pixels-per-inch that means that 20 of those units equal one pixel.